# Prestashop Order Notification Emails not sending

Tags: php, email, prestashop

I seem to have a problem with sending and receiving order alerts on my presta shop site.

The customer should get an email upon placing an order (which they are not) and I am also not receiving an email notifying me of the new order

I am using :
Prestashop 1.6.1.1
Mail Alerts Module is installed, updated, and configured correctly
Mail is set on SMTP, and not PHP

I can successfully send a test mail from the email configuration screen, and my IMAP email settings state that they are "syncing"

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an email address from your website (example : contact@yourwebsite.com) and use php send.